# Asynchronous calls in my netty Client does not get handled

Tags: asynchronous, client, netty

I have written a Netty server which sends asynchronous messages. The server is working as expected.

I can telnet to the server with a couple of telnet sessions and the asynchronous messages gets written out.

I have written a Netty Client but the client seems to be **event driven** and not **asynchronous**. On the server when the client connects; the server writes back to the client "Welcome" and the messages get handled in the client by the messageReceived event, any asynchronous event does not fire any event within the SimpleChannelHandler.

Question: How do I get the Netty client to pick up asynchronous message/events? At the moment it is event driven.

Just to add, the client is the Netty Telnet client.[http://netty.io/docs/stable/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/telnet/package-summary.html]

**The Server Code**

```
//---------Server code---------------
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.Channel;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannelFactory;

public class TestServer {
    private final ServerBootstrap clientServerBootstrap;
    private EchoServerFactory echoServerFactory;
    private Channel appChannel;

    public TestServer() {
        this.clientServerBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(
            new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
                Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));
        this.clientServerBootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            TestServer test = new TestServer();
            test.start();

            for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                long time = System.currentTimeMillis()+1000;
                String data = "setPhase();d(1,1,2.2342,"+time+");";
                System.out.println(data);
                test.write(data);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        echoServerFactory = new EchoServerFactory();
        clientServerBootstrap.setPipelineFactory(echoServerFactory);
        InetSocketAddress isaApp = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9090);
        appChannel = clientServerBootstrap.bind(isaApp);
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                stop();
            }
        }));
    }

    public void write(String message) throws Exception {
        echoServerFactory.write(message);
    }

    public void stop() {
        clientServerBootstrap.releaseExternalResources();
    }
}

//---------------Factory----------------------------
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelPipeline;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelPipelineFactory;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.Delimiters;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.string.StringDecoder;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.string.StringEncoder;

public class EchoServerFactory implements ChannelPipelineFactory {
    EchoServerHandler handler = new EchoServerHandler();

    public EchoServerHandler getHandler() {
        return handler;
    }

    public void write(String message) throws Exception {
        handler.write(message);
    }

    public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
        // Create a default pipeline implementation.
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.pipeline();

        // Add the text line codec combination first,
    pipeline.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
    pipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
    pipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());
    // and then business logic.
    pipeline.addLast("handler", handler);
    return pipeline;
    }
}

//---------------Handler----------------------------

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffer;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.Channel;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelEvent;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFutureListener;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelStateEvent;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChildChannelStateEvent;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ExceptionEvent;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.MessageEvent;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.WriteCompletionEvent;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.group.ChannelGroup;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroup;

public class EchoServerHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {
    private static final Logger logger =     Logger.getLogger(EchoServerHandler.class.getName());

    static final ChannelGroup channels = new DefaultChannelGroup();

    public void write(String message) throws Exception {
        channels.write(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
        Channel channel = e.getChannel();
        channels.add(channel);
        channel.write("Welcome\n\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void channelDisconnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
         // Unregister the channel from the global channel list
         // so the channel does not receive messages anymore.
         //channels.remove(e.getChannel());
    }

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
        // Send back the received message to the remote peer.
        System.out.println("------------------------->"+e.getMessage());
        Channel ch = e.getChannel();
        ChannelFuture f = ch.write(e.getMessage());

       /* f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
                Channel ch = future.getChannel();
                System.out.println("Completed : "+ch.isOpen());
            }
         });*/
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e) {
        // Close the connection when an exception is raised.
        logger.log(
                Level.WARNING,
                "Unexpected exception from downstream.",
                e.getCause());
        e.getChannel().close();
    }
}
```

**The Client Code**

```
//---------------- Client Code -------------------
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.Channel;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketChannelFactory;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

/**
 * Simplistic telnet client.
 */
public class TelnetClient {

    private final String host;
    private final int port;

    public TelnetClient(String host, int port) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void run() throws IOException {
        // Configure the client.
        ClientBootstrap bootstrap = new ClientBootstrap(
                new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(
                        Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                        Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));

        // Configure the pipeline factory.
        bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new TelnetClientPipelineFactory());
        bootstrap.setOption("tcpNoDelay", true);
        // Start the connection attempt.
        ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));

        // Wait until the connection attempt succeeds or fails.
        Channel channel = future.awaitUninterruptibly().getChannel();
        if (!future.isSuccess()) {
            future.getCause().printStackTrace();
            bootstrap.releaseExternalResources();
            return;
        }

        // Read commands from the stdin.
        ChannelFuture lastWriteFuture = null;
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        for (;;) {
            String line = in.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }

            // Sends the received line to the server.
            lastWriteFuture = channel.write(line + "\r\n");

            // If user typed the 'bye' command, wait until the server closes
            // the connection.
            if (line.toLowerCase().equals("bye")) {
                channel.getCloseFuture().awaitUninterruptibly();
                break;
            }
        }

        // Wait until all messages are flushed before closing the channel.
        if (lastWriteFuture != null) {
            lastWriteFuture.awaitUninterruptibly();
        }

        // Close the connection.  Make sure the close operation ends because
        // all I/O operations are asynchronous in Netty.
        channel.close().awaitUninterruptibly();

        // Shut down all thread pools to exit.
        bootstrap.releaseExternalResources();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       try {
        // Parse options.
        String host = "127.0.0.1";
        int port = 9090;

        new TelnetClient(host, port).run();
       } catch(Exception ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}

//---------------- Client Factory -------------------
import static org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.*;

import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelPipeline;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelPipelineFactory;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.Delimiters;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.string.StringDecoder;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.string.StringEncoder;

/**
 * Creates a newly configured {@link ChannelPipeline} for a new channel.
 */
public class TelnetClientPipelineFactory implements ChannelPipelineFactory {



    public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
        // Create a default pipeline implementation.
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = pipeline();

        // Add the text line codec combination first,
        pipeline.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(1118192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
        pipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
        pipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());

        // and then business logic.
        pipeline.addLast("handler", new TelnetClientHandler2());

        return pipeline;
    }
}

//----------------- Client handler -------------------
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelEvent;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelStateEvent;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChildChannelStateEvent;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ExceptionEvent;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.MessageEvent;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.WriteCompletionEvent;

/**
 * Handles a client-side channel.
 */
public class TelnetClientHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TelnetClientHandler.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
        System.out.println("messageReceived");
        String message = (String) e.getMessage();
        parseMessage(message);
    }

    private void parseMessage(String message) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Messatge --> "+message);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getCause());
        logger.log(Level.WARNING,"Unexpected exception from downstream.", e.getCause());
        e.getChannel().close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not quite clear, in Netty, request and response are handled separately(the calling thread will proceed immediately after submitting the request: that is asynchronous), you want to fire some other event when a message is received or you want to write in asynchronous style with callbacks to handle the response?

Comment: @Jestan, I have added my server and client code. I hope this makes things a bit clearer. My problem is that my Netty client does only get the "Welcome" message and not the other messages "setPhase();d(1,1,2.2342,1327816096855);..." while all telnet sessions via the OS gets all the messages. My expectation is that the client will receive all incoming messages via the  messageReceived event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using delimiter based frame decoder in the Netty Client App, it expects the delimiter at end of each message, but it looks like the server is not sending message with delimiter.

> String data = "setPhase();d(1,1,2.2342,"+time+");";
>                   System.out.println(data);
>                   test.write(data);

after above messages are sent, frame decoder is keep waiting even after it received many messages. It works in telnet because, telnet session expects one character at a time. You have done it correctly only for the first message.

> channel.write("Welcome\n\n");